# Output an image from a URL without downloading it on the server answering the request

Tags: php, amazon-cloudfront

I am using cloud-front to speed up delivery of some content. I am a little confused when it comes to 'outputting content'. Lets say for example I have a website mysite.com, and when I navigate to mysite.com/fetchimage.php I want to output an image from cloudfront as if the User was directly accessing that image.

I've already found some ways to do this. However, I want my webserver to 'return' the cloudfront image directly as if it was serving it, but I don't want to be downloading it from cloudfront and then outputting the contents of the image that way.

I want the request to be answered by my server, but I want the user to download the contents of the image directly from cloudfront (so my webserver isn't bogged down with all that traffic).

Comment: not sure I understand your question correctly but you should set the image src to the remote url if it allows you to directly link it. like this: `echo '<img src="'.$cloud_url_of_the_image.'" />';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible. You can't have your server serve a remote image unless it downloads it first. The best I think you can do is trigger a redirect from your fetchimage.php file:

`header('Location: ' . $urlOnCloudFront, true, 301);`